# multiple colours on matlab histogram

Tags: matlab, colors, histogram

Hi I am trying to get multiple colours on a matlab histogram - i think the following should do it:

```
figure
hist(ligand,50)
h=findobj(gca,'Type','patch');
set(h,'FaceColor',[0 .5 .5],'EdgeColor','w')
hold on;
hist(potassium,50)
g=findobj(gca,'Type','patch');
set(g,'FaceColor',[0 1 1],'EdgeColor','w')
hold on;
hist(rectifier,50)
title('Alignment to AFP1')
xlabel('Score'); ylabel('Number of Sequences')
hold off;
```

where the first colour is [0 .5 .5], the second [0 1 1] and the third is the default colour. However even though I have specified two separate colours for the first two using two handles, h and g - both are the same colour, using the g handle.

What am I doing wrong?

edit - this is for Luis Mendos's suggestion - I am getting an "index exceeds matrix dimensions" with the following

```
figure
hist(ligand,50)
g=findobj(gca,'Type','patch');
set(g(1),'FaceColor',[0 .5 .5],'EdgeColor','w')
hold on;
hist(potassium,50)
set(g(2),'FaceColor',[0 1 1],'EdgeColor','w')
hist(rectifier,50)
title('Alignment to AFP1')
xlabel('Score'); ylabel('Number of Sequences')
hold off;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using h = hist(ligand, 50) instead of using gca?

Comment: I think the problem is `g` is a two-element vector. Try `set(g(1),'FaceColor',[0 .5 .5],'EdgeColor','w')`, `set(g(2),'FaceColor',[0 1 1],'EdgeColor','w')`

Comment: @lhcgeneva `hist` doesn't return a handle. It will return the bin count

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `g` is a two-element vector, because it includes the two histograms that have already been plotted. Remove the lines with `h` (lines 3 and 4) and replace the line `set(g,...)` by

```
set(g(1),'FaceColor',[0 .5 .5],'EdgeColor','w')
set(g(2),'FaceColor',[0 1 1],'EdgeColor','w')
```

Comment: Hi Luis - thanks again for answering one of my questions. there seems to be a problem when adding the second line of your suggestion giving me a matirx out of bounds error. i'll update my question with the current code I am using.

Comment: @brucezepplin In your updated code, you need to move the lines third (`g=findobj...`) and fourth (`set(g(1)...`) right after the second `hist`, and before `set(g(2)...`. Try it and tell me if it works

Comment: @brucezeppelin You add the `findobj` line after the two histograms have been plotted, so that `g` contains both of them